# Image matching in Cloud

Tags: image, opencv, cloud, matching, phash

How to check whether two images are similar or not? One image is captured by a cellphone and other is stored at cloud, without sending the whole image to cloud? I found out that extracting feature points from the source image and using Histogram matching at cloud can solve my problem. Is there any better approach like using a hashing functions such as pHash.

Comment: Very interesting question - this study may be of interest: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~winston/papers/su13enabling.pdf. I wonder of some sort of iterative approach might be a good idea also - i.e. do a low bit rate rough match and then do more detailed matches or checks on images which are good candidates.

Comment: BTW if you want just an off the shelf solution there are several such as http://www.kooaba.com/en/how_it_works

Answer (score 0):

using pHash might be a great solution for your problem. It really depends on if the pHash functions (DCT hash, Radial hash, Mexican hat wavelet) turn out to match the images that your app uses.

If you can generate a hash of the image on android then the send the hash to the cloud, on the cloud, compute the hash of the cloud image and compare it the hash from the Android using the Hamming Distance.

This will give you a measure of similarity without sending images because you are doing the hash generation locally on both ends.